# Typescript why is a React <Component /> as typeof Component invalid and what is the proper way to do that?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Below is just a clip of sandbox code showing the problem:

```
type CProps = { prop: string };

function C({ prop }: CProps) {
    return <div>{prop}</div>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
    data: typeof C[] = ["a", "b"].map((l) => <C prop={l} />); //data TS error
    // render() {}
}
```

`data` has the TS error:

```
Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type '(({ prop }: CProps) => Element)[]'.
  Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '({ prop }: CProps) => Element'.
    Type 'ReactElement<any>' provides no match for the signature '({ prop }: CProps): Element'.
```

This is a simple version of an issue I am running into which is essentially:

`<MyComponent ... /> as MyComponent`

Throws that TS error. What should `as MyComponent` be?

Edit: Or more accurately, what is the type of `<MyComponent />` vs `MyComponent`. How can I have `<MyComponent />` express type as more than `Element`?

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-1u9kr1?file=/src/index.tsx:134-340)

Answer (score 1):

The sandbox error was much easier to read and I realized that going from:

`typeof MyComponent` -> `ReactElement<typeof MyComponent>` fixed my issues.